# Find the probability that component 2 functions given that the system does not function

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

The system diagrammed below will function if a path from A to B can be found through independently functioning components. Component i functions with probability Pi, i = 1, 2, 3, 4, where P1 = 0.7, P2 = 0.95, P3 = 0.9, P4 = 0.8

Find the probability that component 2 functions given that the system does not function.

[image]

So what I tried was:

So it's asking for $P(2|S')$, where S is the system is functioning, and S' is the system is not functioning.

I proceeded by doing $P(2|S')$ = $\left( \frac{P(2 \cap S')}{P(S')} \right)$

Then I figured since the components were independent, I could break the numerator up into $\left( \frac{P(2)P(S')}{P(S')} \right)$, which would let me cancel out P(S'), leaving me with P(2) = 0.95.

Is this the correct way of thinking about this, or would I need to use another property like Bayes?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that. D is the system is function, and D' is the system is not functioning. But I'm going to add a note in my original post and change it to S and S'.

Comment: Yeah, I figured ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that $2$ and $S$ are independent is not correct: $2$ functioning or not functioning has a definite effect on there being such a path: with $2$ functioning there is more likely to be a path then with $2$ not functioning, and the same goes for the other components.  So, while the events $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$ are all independent of each other, neither of them are independent of $S$.

And yes, you'll need to use Bayes... which means, among other things, that you need to figure out $P(S'|2)$

Well, given that $2$ is working correctly, and thus the 'signal' getting to the 'middle', the probability of the system not functioning is the probability of both $3$ and $4$ not functioning (otherwise, the system would function), and since $3$ and $4$ are independent, we get:

$$P(S'|2) = P(3' \cap 4') = P(3') \cdot P(4') = (1-P(3))\cdot(1-P(4)) = $$

$$(1-0.9)\cdot(1-0.8)=0.1\cdot0.2=0.02$$

Comment: If you could point me in the right direction, that would be helpful. Since I would need to use Bayes, that would mean I start by letting $P(2|S')$ = $\left( \frac{P(S'|2)P(2)}{P(S'|1)P(1) + P(S'|2)P(2) + P(S'|3)P(3) + P(S'|4)P(4)} \right)$, is this correct? If so, how would I go about calculating the P(S'|1), P(S'|2), P(S'|3), and P(S'|4) part?

Comment: I'll add the $P(S'|2)$ to my answer ...

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Doadle OK, added the $P(S'|2)$ to my Answer. Also, while your Bayesian formula certainly works, it may be a bit easier to work with: $P(2|S') = \frac{P(S'|2)\cdot P(2)}{P(S')}$, and to compute $P(S')=1-P(S)$

Comment: @Doadle You're welcome! :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, just wanted a quick confirmation that I wasn't messing up calculating P(S).Since 1 and 2 are parallel, 3 and 4 are parallel, and (1 and 2) and (3 and 4) are a series. It would be correct to say P(S) = [1 - (1 - 0.7)(1 - 0.95)]$*$[1-(1 - 0.9)(1 - 0.8)], yeah?

Comment: @Doadle Correct!

Comment: Perfect, thanks again!

Comment: @Doadle No problem ... see how computing $P(S')$ was a little easier that way?

Comment: Yeah, definitely. It makes a bit more sense intuitively as well, at least to me.

Comment: @Doadle Yes, that too!